# List of Publication Targets using Tridion Core Service?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

How would I get a list of Publication Targets with the Tridion Core Service?  I see this code sample to get the Target Info, but cannot find a way to get the list from the Core Service.  Maybe it is part of the Publication object?

```
var pubtarget = (PublicationTargetData)client.Read("tcm:0-21-65537", readoption);
```

Also, if there is a way to get this via the Anguilla JavaScript client it would also be cool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var filter = new PublicationTargetsFilterData();
var pubTargets = ClientAdmin.GetSystemWideList(filter);
var pubTargetsXml = ClientAdmin.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);
```

You can set additional filter properties on `filter` object

Answer (score 7):

user978511 already answered how to do it using the Core Service, so let me just answer how you can do it using Anguilla:

```js
var system = $models.getItem($const.TCMROOT);
var list = system.getListPublicationTargets();
```

From then on, it's a normal list -- so you'll want to check `isLoaded()` and call `load()` if it returns `false` (hooking into the "load"/"loadfailed" events for the callback).

The Publication Targets are available either as XML through the `getXml()` method or as an array through the `getItems()` method (which returns an array of model items -- so again, you can check `isLoaded()` on those, etc.)